# Two if statement is executed in java code

Tags: java, netbeans

Im currently trying to do a validation for staff login form. but i realized in my validation output that whenever i enter a value to the username text field, it still pops up the message "please enter your username" then the "invalid credentials"message box. Here is my code down below :

```
 String username = usernameTxt.getText();
    String password = passwordTxt.getText();


    if  (username.contains(""))
  {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Enter Your Username Credentials.");
    }
    else  if (password.contains (""))
  {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Enter Your Password Credentials.");
    } 
   else if (password.contains ("") && (username.contains("")))
  {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Enter Your Login Credentials.");
    }
   if ((username.contains("staff") && password.contains ("pass")))

    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Login Successfull","Success",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        passwordTxt.setText(null);
        usernameTxt.setText(null);
        staffdashboard sd = new staffdashboard();
        sd.setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(false);   
    }    
    else  
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Login Details","Login Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        passwordTxt.setText(null);
        usernameTxt.setText(null);
    }
```

[enter user message box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr8Du.png) 
[invalid login details message box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jlh9.png)

What am i missing out and how do stop the form to output 2 message box at once?

Comment: Any String contains empty string. I think you wanted to use username.equals("")

Comment: A string will always contain "".  You probably want `password.isEmpty()`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the first if statement: `username.contains("")`

Each String contains empty String. 
You should replace it with `if("".equals(username))`

Or use `StringUtils.isBlank(username);`

And the same for all the `contains("")`

Comment: just to confirm, must i do this for  else  if (password.contains ("")) as well or usually only for the first line of code?

Comment: exactly! You should replace all your contains("")

Answer (score 0):

@Naya's answer is correct, however you may want to remove any empty spaces assuming they are not allowed as valid input, so :

```
if  (username.trim().equals("")) ...
else  if (password.trim.equals("")) ...
...
```